# I am having errors when i deal with this object i create

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I cant seem to figure this out, its probably simple. I have a customer class and I am trying to create an object form that and its not working I get an undeclared identifier error and a syntax error ; missing before identifier c1. thanks

```
class Customer{
    string customerID;
    string list;
public:
    Customer(void);
    ~Customer(void);



    string getcustomerID(){
        return customerID;
    }
    string getList(){
        return list;
    }
    void setcustomerID(string x){
        customerID = x;
    }
    void setList(int x){
        if(x==1)
            list = "bread";
        if(x==2)
            list = "eggs";
        if(x==3)
            list = "cheese";
    }

};




void checkout(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    int random = rand() % 3 + 1;

    Customer c1;
    c1.setcustomerID(0);
```

Comment: You're not defining your constructor anywhere.

Comment: At the  end I declare an object, but it wont take

Comment: He means you didn't define the constructor `Customer(void)` anywhere, you only declared it. You're missing its code. Also, note that in C++ you don't need to specify `void` for empty parameter lists. You can just use empty parentheses (`Customer()`).

Comment: Does that mean that I need to do a Customer c1 = new Customer() in the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a default constructor (and a destructor). If you want a really simple one (and make it compile) just do this:

```
Customer() {}
~Customer() {}
```

EDIT:
KerrekSB is right, on this particular case you are better off not defining or declaring either of them.

Comment: There's no point in defining a destructor like that. On the contrary, this makes your class have a non-trivial destructor for no reason, so that's actually *undesirable*.

Comment: I think I have that, on lines 5 and 6.

Comment: @user1504257, Yours isn't defined. Also, you can leave the constructor out as well if you have no other constructors.

Comment: @user1504257, notice the differences, this Customer(void); is different than this: Customer() {}

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks, totally agree with you, just trying to simplify things.